# localizing image paths within css

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, localization

I am currently working on localizing my application which is based on the .net framework v3.5, which uses the jquery client side library.

I successfully localized most of my application, on screen text via resource files, client side text via a resource javascript file and html mark up images via .net c# code.

When localizing my images, the simple change is to update the path to image to include the cultures folder eg. For english - en, spanish - es etc. So a sample image path would be

/image/folder1/en/image.gif

/image/folder2/es/image.gif

I have achieved this in my .net code and all works fine.

However I have run in to an issue. Some of my images are background images set in css. Unfortunately this raises an issue as I am unable to localize something like this:

```
h1 {background-image:url("../../Images/folder1/<<culture>>/image1.gif");background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

So I am looking for suggestion as how I could resolve this. Could I pass a javascript variable value to the css file? I could create a httphandler and update my css prior to rendering but would prefer to go with this for last resort as I don't want every css file being processed through iis.

Any tips would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another possibility is to set lang attribute for the body (or HTML element of your interest), so that rendered HTML page will show something like this:

```
<body lang="es">
  <h1>...</h1>
```

Then you can use CSS lang pseudo-selector to localize the content:

```
h1:lang(es) {background-image:url("../../Images/folder1/es/image1.gif");}
h1:lang(en) {background-image:url("../../Images/folder1/en/image1.gif");}
```

This is standard (as in W3C recommended) way of localizing CSS files.

Comment: This seems like a perfect solution. Do all browsers support this?

Comment: This is CSS2 feature, so theoretically all browsers **should** support it. However, to be honest it seems like IE9 have a problem (earlier versions did not). It might be related to declaration (I mean DTD), so I can't be 100% sure. But IE9 could be switched to compatibility view, which should resolve the problem (if any). Other browsers seems to work.

Comment: +1 I've come across a similar solution while working on a specific project. But this has some limitation : I mean if the amount of differences is too big, breaking up the original css file into one common base and multiple localized ones can be more maintainable.

Comment: That is unfortunately true. Using built-in CSS Localization Mechanism could quickly result in unmanageable and unmaintainable CSS files. In such case full-fledged mechanism is needed (for example serving CSS files contents via Handlers). Unfortunately, this would require quite an implementation effort...

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution could be creating another css file for every language that only includes the modified image paths, and load it after the main css.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have too many elements with `BG` images, you could give those elements `class names` and hard code the language ref. Eg.

```
h1.engish {background-image:url("../../Images/folder1/en/image1.gif")...; 
h1.spanish {background-image:url("../../Images/folder1/es/image1.gif")...;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're dynamically generating your CSS file, you can't pass variables to it.

You could put the background image paths inline, though, by wrapping them in  tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the CSS dinamically

```
<link href="sitecss.aspx" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Then in `sitecss.aspx` you can do the same you do in the code:

```
h1 {background-image:url("../../Images/folder1/<%= culture %>/image1.gif");}
```

Use a different parameter when calling the file to prevent caching between cultures:

```
<link href="sitecss.aspx?culture=<%= culture %>&ver=<%= siteversion %>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```